# How to populate rows of kendo-grid dynamically?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

My kendo-grid:

```
<kendo-grid>    
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="gridColumns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}" title="{{column}}">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-dataItem >
                <span title={{column}}>{{column}}</span>                
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

I have a `JSON` response in the following format:

```
Books: [
{
   BookName: "Hello World!",
   PageCount: 455
},
{
   MagazineName: "Hello World!",
   PageCount: 455
}
],

FirstName: "Jon",
LastName: "Arlington",
City: "London"
```

and I've managed to populate columns from the `JSON` like this:

```
let gridColumns = ["FirstName", "LastName", "BookName", "MagazineName", "PageCount",
                   "MagazineName", "PageCount" ];
```

*And it works okay:*

[image]

My question is how can I add rows to columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dataSource's [`add()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add) method:

```
var book = {
    MagazineName: "Hello World!",
    PageCount: 455,
    FirstName: "Jon",
    LastName: "Arlington",
    City: "London"
};

grid.dataSource.add(book);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/owAPU)

Comment: Will it work in Angular 2?(sorry I am far from my PC).

Comment: @StepUp its a built-in feature of kendo, so it should work.